# Hide element which is not a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide an element which is not a certain class via jQuerys [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) :

```
 <a href="#" id="c_1" class="content-btn">Content 1</a>
 <a href="#" id="c_2" class="content-btn">Content 2</a>

 <div class="post-item c_1"></div>
 <div class="post-item c_2"></div>
```

and

```
var thisContent;
jQuery('.content-btn').click(function() {
    thisContent = this.id;
    jQuery('.post_item').not('.'+thisContent).fadeOut();
}
```

am I using  `.not()` method wrong in this context, because it seems not to work!

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector needs to be

`jQuery('.post-item')`

And you need to close the ) at the end of your jQuery, like this:

```
var thisContent;
jQuery('.content-btn').click(function() {
    thisContent = this.id;
    jQuery('.post-item').not('.'+thisContent).fadeOut();
});
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaNXjg for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(element).hasClass(".clasname").fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

as @AND Finally noticed modify your selector .. and while you use click on Anchor you need to use **e.preventDefault;**  try this

```
jQuery('.content-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    thisContent = this.id;
    jQuery('.post-item').not('.'+thisContent).fadeOut();
    $('.'+thisContent).fadeIn();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3a5vycc/)